# Redirect Android HTTP traffic through OpenVPN UDP connection

Tags: proxy, openvpn

I have set up a server with OpenVPN and Squid, by making my computer connect to the server's OpenVPN (TUN interface UDP connection), we are in the same LAN network, and Squid on this server allows my computer to surf the internet by its proxy function, simply by setting computer's Chrome proxy to `10.200.0.1:3128`.

I have set up my Android phone with the OpenVPN client, it can connect to the server too (Although I can not ping Android IP - `10.200.0.2` from the server side, which is weird to me).
However, I see no Android app has the same proxy setting as what is in the computer's Chrome. All my HTTP traffic still goes through the WLAN interface rather than the TUN interface.

I am not sure if the OpenVPN Android client's proxy setting can help. I tried it, but the OpenVPN client prompted an error message:

> option_error: can not connect via TCP-based proxy because no tcp server entries exist in profile.

Does it mean I should use a TCP OpenVPN connection to fix this error? or should I find another way to redirect the HTTP traffic through VPN channel?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do so is to connect your phone to the computer and run adb in the command line.

- `adb shell settings put global http_proxy ipaddress:port` to set your phone's global proxy to the IP address.
- `adb shell settings put global http_proxy :0` try this to turn off the global proxy.

Very unfortunately, the connection was shut down by GFW during last Friday night. An obfuscation method must be employed to counter this issue. I have no time for this, so it leaves me with no choice but to buy a ladder.